# How to disable security pop ups of MS Outlook in C#?

Tags: c#, office-interop, outlook

How to disable security pop ups of MS Outlook using C#? 
I am getting the security pop up, while trying to initiate outlook task to be created using my c# application. (Using Microsoft Office Outlook 11.0 Object Library))

Screen would looks like

[alt text http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/2988/securitypopup.jpg](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/2988/securitypopup.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to deal with this same issue trying to send Outlook email from Access. I used [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), a third-party COM library that wraps the calls to Outlook and avoids those annoying popups. It is free unless you want to redistribute it, in that case you would need to [buy the redistributable version](http://shareit1.element5.com/programs.html?productid=139568) for $199.

> **How Outlook Redemption works**
>
> Redemption is a regular COM library;
>   once registered on the system, it is
>   accessible to any programming language
>   (VB, VBA, VC++, Delphi, etc).
>   Redemption uses Extended MAPI (which
>   is not affected by the Security Patch
>   since it is not accessible to the
>   scripting languages) to duplicate the
>   functionality blocked by the Security
>   Patch. All Safe*Item Redemption
>   objects have an Item property which
>   must be set to an Outlook item. Once
>   set, you can access any properties and
>   methods, both blocked and not blocked.
>   For the blocked properties and
>   functions, Redemption objects
>   completely bypass the Outlook object
>   model and behave exactly like Outlook
>   objects with no Security Patch
>   applied. For the properties and
>   methods not blocked by the Security
>   Patch, all calls are transparently
>   forwarded to the Outlook object that
>   you assign to the Item property. With
>   this approach changes to your code are
>   minimal: you only change the way you
>   declare the objects, but not the rest
>   of your code that actually accesses
>   both blocked and not blocked
>   properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [a component of Add-In Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/) to get around this issue. It's only $150.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I wrote a method to click on the dialog window whenever it appears: [Defeating 'A program is trying to access email' with SendMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598596/defeating-a-program-is-trying-to-access-email-with-sendmessage). My method runs in a continuous loop in a separate thread, checking for the darned security window every second or so.
There is a problem with my code in that it's not clicking on the **Allow** button properly. Hoping to resolve this issue soon. Anyone else wrote their own solution?