# Defeating 'A program is trying to access email' with SendMessage

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook, office-interop

I am writing an application in C# that uses Office Outlook Interop (2010; version 14) to access email data through MAPI.

So far I have to manually and repeatedly click Allow in Outlook's "**A program is trying to access email address information stored in Outlook**" security popup (screenshot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/gj8to.png).

I tried to write a method to do the clicking automatically, but unsuccessfully. The clicking takes place, but Outlook Interop throws the following exception during the next read operation:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)

Here's an extract from code that uses SendMessage to click on the Allow button:

```
private const Int32 BM_CLICK = 0x00F5;
private const Int32 GWL_STYLE = -16;
private const Int32 CB_SETCURSEL = 0x14E;
private const Int32 WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;
private const Int32 WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202;

private const string dialogClass = "#32770";
private const string dialogTitle = "Microsoft Outlook";
const string tickBoxTitle = @"&Allow access for";
const string tickBoxClass = @"Button";

private const int ThreadSleepTime = 1000;
private const int ThreadUiSleepTime = 20;

IntPtr popupHandle;
IntPtr tickHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr comboHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr allowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
while ((popupHandle = FindWindow(dialogClass, dialogTitle)) != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // Get object handles
    tickHandle = FindWindowEx(popupHandle, tickHandle, tickBoxClass, tickBoxTitle);
    comboHandle = FindWindowEx(popupHandle, tickHandle, null, null);
    allowHandle = FindWindowEx(popupHandle, comboHandle, null, null);

    // Click on tickbox until the combobox is enabled
    while ((GetWindowLong(comboHandle, GWL_STYLE) & 0x8000000) != 0)
    {
        SendMessage(tickHandle, BM_CLICK, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ThreadUiSleepTime);
    }

    // Set dropdown box selection index to 3rd row
    SendMessage(comboHandle, CB_SETCURSEL, 3, 0);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ThreadUiSleepTime);

    // Click Allow button
    //SendMessage(allowHandle, BM_CLICK, new IntPtr(1), IntPtr.Zero);

    SendMessage(allowHandle, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(MakeLParam(5, 5)));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(ThreadUiSleepTime); 
    SendMessage(allowHandle, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, new IntPtr(MakeLParam(5, 5)));
}
```

Why does SendMessage not work and how can I make this work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid Outlook security alert when reading outlook message from C# program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235231/how-to-avoid-outlook-security-alert-when-reading-outlook-message-from-c-sharp-pr)

Answer (score 2):

You should use EMAPI, which does not display these warnings.
The [Redemption library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/home.htm) provides a convenient wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

There's not supposed to be a way to override due to spam abuse.

However, using another thread to hunt down and press the button works.

Please note that SendMessage doesn't work for mouse buttons. You have to use the accessability API or WM_COMMAND.

Oh, and incidentally, don't use delay loops with resending the same message.

Comment: Also note that none of these work if the machine is locked, in terminal services, etc It has to be a logged in and visible session somewhere.

Comment: Some of the accessibility APIs work from the service session. WM_COMMAND is known to do so.

Comment: @Joshua, my method (above) does run in a separate thread. In the long term I will try to re-write the application using Redemption, but for now I really need to get this working. Presently my code ticks the tickbox and selects a 10 minute timeout, but even though it **appears** to click on Allow my application crashes immediately thereafter as if Deny was clicked. Can you please help me implement the function using WM_COMMAND as suggested? Will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to send WM_COMMAND to the parent window the same way a BUTTON object would have. Read the documentation on MSDN.